# Pascal an array of records

Tags: arrays, sorting, record, pascal

```
program R3cord;
  type rekord = record
  end;

  var i,d,j,c,x,y,a : integer;

  mas : array[1..5] of rekord;
begin
  x := 4;
  y := 5;

  for i := 1 to y do
    Read(mas[i]);

  for i := 1 to x do
  begin
    d := i;

    for j :=  i + 1 to y do
      if mas[j] > mas[d] then
        d := j;

    c := mas[i]; mas[i] := mas[d]; mas[d] := c;
  end;

  for i := 1 to 5 do
    Write(mas[i],' ');
end.
```

I'm having a trouble here, as you can see this program will read user's input and will sort it in descending order. I need to have a row number near number which was before the sorting. I've read that record is good for it, but I can't find any tutorials how to do it.

Comment: Okay I fixed that part. The thing I meant is : when I enter in numbers everyone of them will have a row number. the array is for example {5,4,6} the row numbers will be 1,2 and 3. And I need them to stay the way they are(row numbers) after sorting so it would be {4,5,6} and the row numbers : 2,1,3. Do you understand now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your record doesn't have anything in it. I think you want:

```
type 
    rekord = record
        value: Integer;
        row: Integer;
    end;
```

And when you read it in:

```
for i := 1 to 5 do
begin
    Read(mas[i].value);
    mas[i].row = i;
end
```

The above will number the rows 1, 2, 3, ...

And in your sort:

```
if mas[j].value > mas[d].value
```

When you swap, be sure to swap the whole record as you're currently doing. Don't just swap the values.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but the row numbers won't sort, they will stay 1,2,3,4,5. I know that when the numbers switches places, the row numbers should switch too, how to do this ?

Comment: @Vilmis: Have you tried that? If you make the modifications I suggested and then run the code, I think you'll find that it works as expected.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/9e445f235edc1b1951f308f57d9426a0.png

Yes I did, did I do something wrong ?

Comment: @Vilmis: That's because you're swapping just the values. You need to swap the entire record. That is: `c := mas[i]; mas[i] = mas[d]; mas[d] = c;`

Comment: But it won't let me compile like this.
https://i.gyazo.com/f3612af2eed575cf9f18d985ade8ad6b.png

Comment: @Vilmis: In your variable declarations, remove `c` from the list of integers, and add a line: `c: rekord;`

Comment: Oh my god  thank you very much, had trouble with this for a few days, thank you very much, but why c has to be a record ?

Comment: @Vilmis: c has to be of type `rekord` because it's the temporary storage space for a value of type `rekord`.